# Resizing Panel Containing UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a UserControl that contains invisible controls, to make them visible, the UserControl resizes.

I need to resize the Panel that contains the UserControl, but I don't know how.

Comment: Do you want to resize it from the user control or from the page? Does it matter?

Comment: From the user control in Window Form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is handled well by the Panel and Form classes without explicit sizing (and without the layout bugs introduced when the user has a high-DPI monitor or uses the large or extra-large font settings.

1) Create a Form with a docked FlowLayoutPanel.

[image: Docked]

2) Set the Form and FlowLayoutPanel's  AutoSize to true and AutoSizeMode to GrowAndShrink

[image: GrowAndShrink]

3) Add your panels and content.

[image: Design]

4) Programmatically set the desired panel's Visible property to hidden

```
hiddenPanel.Visible = false;
```

[image: Hidden]

5) or true

```
hiddenPanel.Visible = true;
```

[image: Visible]

Comment: Also, panels have to be "top-docked" in the flowLayoutPanel. Then, use right click -> BringToFront / SendToBack to order the dock order.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in the usercontrol:

```
Size last = new Size(0, 0);

private void Me_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (last != new Size(0, 0)) {
        this.Parent.Size = Size.Add(this.Parent.Size, Size.Subtract(this.Size, last));
    }
    last = this.Size;
}
```

Will also retain margins (e.g., if the panel is larger than your usercontrol or has other controls beside your usercontrol.)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to resize it to a particular size, you can do it on the code behind:

```
Size panelSize = new Size(500, 500);
usercontrol1.Parent.Size = panelSize;
```

You could add this code to the usercontrol if that is where you wish to resize from.

Answer (score 0):

To resize the control , call scale of to the control.

```
           // To zoom in controls.
            foreach (Control c in MyFlowLayoutPanel.Controls)
            {
                PictureBox ptc = c as PictureBox;

                if (null != ptc)
                {
                    Point pt = new Point(2, 2);
                    SizeF sf = new SizeF(pt);
                    c.Scale(sf);
                }
            }
```

// To zoom out controls.
                                foreach (Control c in MyFlowLayoutPanel.Controls)
                                {
                                    PictureBox ptc = c as PictureBox;

```
                                if (null != ptc)
                                {
                                    SizeF sf = new SizeF(0.5F, 0.5F);
                                    c.Scale(sf);
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this topic is pretty old but I want to add my method, as well...

If you have a Panel containing a UserControl you can easially resize the panel.Controls by firing Form1_Resize event.

```
 private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Control control in MasterPanel.Controls)
            {
                control.Size = MasterPanel.Size;
            }

        }
```

Just make sure that you anchor its content properly.